# Why ↵ is not recognized when we copy data to HTML form. Line breaks are removed automatically when we paste or view

Tags: html, kendo-ui

Why ↵ is not recognized when we copy data to HTML form. Line breaks are removed automatically when we paste or view

Clipboard Data when i paste :- `"td↵    {padding-top:1px;↵  padding-right:1px;"`

what i see in Kendo Editor UI or HTML page :-  `td {padding-top:1px; padding-right:1px`

All line breaks are gone. Shall i replace ↵ with `<br>` ? what can be the solution

I want to paste it like below and not in one line.

```
"td  {padding-top:1px;
      padding-right:1px;
```

Tried below:- Does not work

```
<div id="editorDiv" class="input-group editorAreaCustom" style="white-space:pre-wrap;" >
                            <textarea id="editor" name="editor" rows="10" style="height:400px;width:93%;white-space:pre-wrap;" /></textarea>                
                        </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the replace function using javascript:

```
text.replace(/\u21B5/g,'<br/>')
```

**21B5** is the unicode for ↵

Comment: MosesDavidowitz -it did not work, still it remains a straight line.

Answer (score -1):

If you control the CSS of the target element into which the text is being copied then add the following style to the CSS:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

More information on [the style here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp):

Comment: <div id="editorDiv" class="input" style="white-space:pre-wrap;" >
<textarea id="editor" name="editor" rows="10" style="height:400px;width:93%;white-space:pre-wrap;" /></textarea>    
</div> - Tired this it does not work when i copy paste

Comment: What is not working? I tried your code in a JSFiddle and can copy text with line breaks in from notepad++